Is it possible to validate a pyrsistent data structure with jsonschema?
I'm toying around with immutable data structures using the pyrsistent library in python.
One of the nice things when representing data with generic data structures is the ability to check data with schemas. Here an example of an immutable data structure in pyrsistent:
from pyrsistent import pmap, pvector
users = pvector([
    pmap({'id': 1, 'name': 'Jack', 'email': 'jack@example.org', 'active': True}),
    pmap({'id': 2, 'name': 'Max', 'email': 'max@example.com', 'active': True}),
    pmap({'id': 3, 'name': 'Allison', 'email': 'allison@example.org', 'active': False}),
    pmap({'id': 4, 'name': 'David', 'email': 'david@example.net', 'active': False})
])

Here is a jsonschema that I would like to use to validate the data:
from jsonschema import validate
schema = {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "integer"},
      "name": {"type": "string"},
      "email": {"type": "string","format": "email"
      },
      "active": {"type": "boolean"}
    },
    "required": ["id", "name", "email", "active"]
  }
}
validate(instance=users, schema=schema)

With the given code there are type errors because jsonschema only works with native types.
Is there an easy or a good way to validate such data structures?
I'm looking for a generalizable solution that also extends to millions of items and deeply nested structures. The ideas are from data-oriented programming.

I think if you convert pmap and pvector to a dictionary list something like this:
plain_users = [dict(user) for user in users]
validate(instance=plain_users, schema=schema)

This is the simplest way which with very complex data can take a long time to compile.
This should work and should not cause errors.
Another way,
I think you can create your own validator something like this to improve the speed of code execution with complex structures and the amount of code.
from pyrsistent import pmap, pvector, PMap, PVector, thaw
from jsonschema import validate,

def validate_pyrsistent_data(data, schema):
    if isinstance(data, PMap):
        data = thaw(data)
    elif isinstance(data, PVector):
        data = [validate_pyrsistent_data(item, schema) for item in data]
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            data[key] = validate_pyrsistent_data(value, schema)
    return data

validated_users = validate_pyrsistent_data(users, schema)
validate(instance=validated_users, schema=schema)


The provided code was just an easy example for clarification. The question is explicitely for large and deep structures for which copying is maybe not such a good idea. A working solution would at least convert the data recursively.

@Pascal You are right I only responded to the error occurring, I did not read to the end my fault. I updated my answer hope it will help you unfortunately I don't know other ways.
You can always use multithreading to speed up your code.
Maybe someone else will know a better way.

You pointed out the solution already provided by pyrsistent - thaw(users). To my understanding this would still convert/copy the whole (large) structure which I wanted to avoid.
